# Windows Temperature Monitor

Tags: windows, hardware, monitor, temperature

As part of an application for a client, I need to have a section which reports temperature information (motherboard, CPU, HDD).  I know there are standalone applications such as Hardware Monitor by CPUID, but again, these are standalone and I require something that I could interface with.

Is there any app like this which has an API or is open source so I can utilize their source code?  I have language preferences other than it needs to run on Windows XP.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You get info like this from WMI.  Download [WMICodeCreator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) to find the query as well as the code you need to write.  Beware that hardware queries like this tend to rely heavily on providers supplied by the hardware or BIOS manufacturer.