# How to get temperature of CPU on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono

How can I get the current temperature of the CPU on Linux?

There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195112/how-to-get-cpu-temperature) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614723/how-to-get-the-cpu-temperature-info-from-bios-using-c) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615682/how-to-get-the-cpu-temperature-info-from-bios-using-c) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273279/windows-temperature-monitor) on getting the CPU temperature using C#, but all of them seem to be Windows specific.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. This is a valid question.

Answer (score 6):

If you know how to read a file in C# , and your computer is ACPI enabled, you may be able to read a file

```
 /proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THRM/temperature
```

on other linux flavors it might be

```
 /proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THM0/temperature
```

You would have to run this using mono on linux of course.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string path = @"/proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THRM/temperature";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not find "+path);
            return;
        }

        string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
        Console.WriteLine(readText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without C#, you can use this command:

```
sudo sensors
```

Labels used in the output can be found in `/etc/sensors3.conf`

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to use the in-built utilities to check the CPU temperature if you don’t want to use third-party apps.

1. To check the CPU temperature without installing a third-party app, use the following command:

   cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp

The output shows the CPU temperature in the five-digit format. For example, 49000 means 49C.

2. If you get several thermal zones and different temperatures, execute the following command to see what a single thermal zone represents:

   Syntax: cat /sys/class/thermal/<thermal_zoneNumber>/type

For example, run cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/type to see the type of thermal zone 0.

The CPU temperature is in the zone labeled x86_pkg_temp.

3. To see what all the thermal zones are referring to, use:

paste <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type) <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp) | column -s $'\t' -t | sed 's/(.)..$/.\1°C/'

The output shows the last stored temperature for that thermal zone in degrees Celsius. In this example, there is only one thermal zone, labeled x86_pkg_temp, which represents the CPU temperature.